# variable type checking while reading a CSV

Tags: python-3.x

I'm reading from a csv and trying to preserve variable types as I read it into an array:

I have the following code:

```
with open(filename,"r") as file:
    file = csv.reader(file)
    #iterate over the rows
    count = 0;
    for row in file:

        #if count is 0 we are hitting the headers of the CSV
        if (count == 0):
            #aggreagte headers as dict keys
            for i in range(0,len(row)):
                data_in[row[i]] = []
        #bin data into headers
                x = '';
        if (count > 0 and count < 2):        
            for key in data_in.keys():
                for i in range(0,len(row)):
                    try:
                        data_in[key].append(float(row[i]))
                    except ValueError:
                        print(row[i])
                        data_in[key].append(str(row[i]))

        count += 1;
```

After going through the loop, all of the variable types in data_in are recorded as strings when I was expecting only 2 to be strings (because of hitting the value error) and the rest to be floats. Why are they all strings and is there a way to preserve floats and strings?

Comment: What does the CSV look like? Can you paste a few lines for us to have a look?

Comment: hey good question -- I think I figured out the problem. I wasn't putting coulmns of the data file into each dictionary item. I was putting each line of the file into the dictionary so therefore the types were all string! Thanks for the help.